# Html form redirects to another page without inserting the data into database

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create one small project where Here in this case I have created one form where I am taking input from the user and then update the data into database but it is not uploading it and it redirects to another page .I am new to PHP please help.

```html
<?php include 'config.php'; ?>
<body>
  <?php 
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phn=$_POST['phone'];
        $amount=$_POST['amount'];
        $sql="insert into donator(first_name,last_name,email,phone_no,amount) values('{$fname}','{$lname}','{$email}','{$phn}','{$amount}')";
        $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      }
  ?>
<div id="header"></div>
 <div class="testbox">
    <form action="charge.php" method="post">
      <div class="banner">
        <h1>Donation Form</h1>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Donation Form</legend>
        <div class="rows">
          <div class="item">
            <label for="fname">First Name<span>*</span></label>
            <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" required />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <label for="lname"> Last Name<span>*</span></label>
            <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <label for="address">Email Address<span>*</span></label>
            <input id="address" type="text" name="email" required />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input id="phone" type="tel"   name="phone" required/>
          </div>
          </fieldset>
          <br/>
          <fieldset>
          <legend>Donation Details</legend>
          <div class="colums">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
          <label for="amount">Donation Amount<span>*</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="amount" value="20.00" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
          <label for="donation">Donation Comments</label>
          <textarea id="donation" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div class="btn-block">
          <button type="submit" name=submit>Donate Now</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thank you sir it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

`$sql = "insert into donator (first_name,last_name,email,phone_no,amount) values('$fname','$lname','$email','$phn','$amount')";`

And keep form action empty `<form action=""></form>`